# Can I use my own Python class with numpy or some other matrix library?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I'd like to be able to do matrix operations using a Python class as the elements—in this case, a simple [Galois field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_field) implementation. It implements the necessary `__add__`, `__mul__`, `__sub__` etc.

At first, I thought this should be possible with [numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), using the `dtype` parameter, but from [the `dtype` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), it seems that `dtype` can't be an arbitrary Python class. For example, I have a class `Galois` which does operations modulo 2:

```
>>> from galois import Galois
>>> Galois(1) + Galois(0)
Galois(1)
>>> Galois(1) + Galois(1)
Galois(0)
```

I can try to use this in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.identity(4, Galois)
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=object)
```

But if I do operations on the matrices, the elements aren't following the methods of my class:

```
>>> b = np.identity(4, Galois)
>>> a+b
array([[2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Is there any way to make this work with numpy?

Is there any other Python matrix library that can do matrix operations (including inversion) on an arbitrary number-like class?

#### Update

Thanks for the answers so far. But I'm still not able to really use it as I hoped. Adds and multiplies seem good, but not matrix inversion. For example, let's try to get the [AES inverse S-box affine transform matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Inverse_S-box) from the [forward S-box affine transform matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Forward_S-box).

```
class Galois(object):
    MODULO = 2

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = int(val) % self.MODULO

    def __add__(self, val):
        return self.__class__((self.val + int(val)) % self.MODULO)
    def __sub__(self, val):
        return self.__class__((self.val - int(val)) % self.MODULO)
    def __mul__(self, val):
        return self.__class__((self.val * int(val)) % self.MODULO)
    def __int__(self):
        return self.val
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%d)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.val)
    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np

    Gv = np.vectorize(Galois)

    a = Gv(np.identity(8)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,-1)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,-2)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,-3)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,-4)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,4)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,5)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,6)) + Gv(np.eye(8,8,7))
    print np.matrix(a)
    print np.matrix(a).I
```

The result:

```
[[Galois(1) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1)
  Galois(1)]
 [Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(1) Galois(1)
  Galois(1)]
 [Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(1)
  Galois(1)]
 [Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(0)
  Galois(1)]
 [Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(0) Galois(0)
  Galois(0)]
 [Galois(0) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(0)
  Galois(0)]
 [Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1)
  Galois(0)]
 [Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(0) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1) Galois(1)
  Galois(1)]]
[[ 0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4 -0.6]
 [-0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4]
 [ 0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6]
 [-0.6  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4]
 [ 0.4 -0.6  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4]
 [ 0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6]
 [-0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4]
 [ 0.4 -0.6  0.4  0.4 -0.6  0.4 -0.6  0.4]]
```

Not the result I hoped for. It seems that for the matrix inversion, numpy just converts the matrix to floats, then does the inversion with plain real numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `object` as the `dtype`, which will allow arbitrary Python objects. I don't think there's any way of specializing a numpy array to accept only one particular class of Python object.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with an example. Am I missing something there?

Comment: The problem is with the creation of your identity matrix, not with the operations on it. If you forcibly replace every element of your `a` and `b` arrays with `Galois` objects then you'll find that `a+b` gives you an array full of `Galois(0)`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, and seems to work. Though I wish numpy's `np.identity` and `np.eye` etc would create the elements of the `dtype` type, using its `__init__` function.

Comment: Use `dtype=object` explicitly. If you give us a class for the dtype, we just assume that you meant `dtype=object`. We don't make a special dtype for your class, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can create and initialize a Numpy object array with another array:

```
import numpy as np

class G:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

I = np.identity(5)
Gv = np.vectorize(G)
GG = Gv(I)

print GG[0,0].x
print GG[0,1].x
```

Comment: However, object dtypes are slow and usually avoided.  Its better practice to create objects that have NumPy array attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your update on matrix inversion:  Using NumPy matrix inversion to invert matrices over Galois fields won't work.  NumPy delegates the task of actually inverting the matrix to [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), which is a linear algebra library written in Fortran.  LAPACK is of course completely unaware of Python classes and operators, and will never be able to call methods on your `Galois` class.  Additionally, their matrix inversion algorithm makes use of comparison operators (like `<` and `>`), which do not make sense for elements of Galois fields.

So your options are either to implement the matrix inversion yourself or to use one of the available implementations.  For example, [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) has a limited support for Galois fields.  [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/doc.html) has support for Galois fields and [some Python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/pari-python/).

Comment: SymPy also has *undocumented* support for Galois fields. But so far I've figured out there is `sympy.polys.domains.FF` so I can do `GF2 = sympy.polys.domains.FF(2)` then do `GF2(1) + GF2(1)` which gives me `SymmetricModularInteger2(0)`. But, I don't know how it could be used in SymPy matrices.

Comment: It seems SymPy isn't yet designed to do matrices of other types (unless I'm missing something), but [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sympy/9356) and [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sympy/9370) show that someone else also wants to, and is thinking about it.

Comment: @Craig: Thanks for the feedback.  It seems not too many people are interested in matrix arithmetic over finite fields.  If you only need matrix inversion for dense matrices, then I'd suggest to implement the Gauss elimination yourself.  It's not too much code, and over finite fields you won't even need pivoting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [sage](http://sagemath.org/) and specifically [galois_group](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/rings/number_field/galois_group.html).

It seems that you are reinventing the wheel. But if you insist doing that you may consider to [subclass ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

Comment: No doubt sage is excellent. But Python has certain advantages over sage I think--e.g. more light-weight, more Windows-friendly. But anyway... can you confirm that sage `galois_group` goes well in sage matrices?

Comment: @Craig: I'm not in a position to confirm anything. But now seeing your update I'll expect that `sage` would be the most `pythonic` tool you can have. Give it just a try and judge it yourself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to have matrix elements behave according to an arbitrary Python class. It is however possible to globally change the behaviour of certain operations, as the following examples show,

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import set_numeric_ops

from numpy import poly1d as poly
from numpy import identity as idt

def gfadd(x,y):
    return np.add(x,y) % 2

set_numeric_ops(add=gfadd)

a = idt(4,np.int)
print a+a
```

produces,

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

and,

```
p = poly([1,0,1])
print p+p
```

gives,

```
0
```

However, you probably want to subclass `ndarray`.