# What would be the Scilab Equivalent of Galois Field in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, scilab

I am trying to write `Reed Solomon` Code in `Scilab`. Coming from `MATLAB`, there doesn't seem to be any direct replacement for the either the `gf()` function or the `rsenc()` function.

Is there any way I could make it work?

```
m = 3; % Number of bits per symbol
n = 2^m-1; k = 3; % Word lengths for code
msg = gf([2 7 3; 4 0 6],m); % Two rows of m-bit symbols
code = rsenc(msg,n,k)
```

Comment: not sure about equivalent, but you can define your own function in ~5-10 lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578172/can-i-use-my-own-python-class-with-numpy-or-some-other-matrix-library

Comment: Neither could I find

Comment: But you have a octave equivalent library gf in communication toolbox