# Sparse matrix operations with matrices valued in a custom class

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am hoping to define a scipy.sparse matrix which is valued in a class which I have defined. For example I have the class for elements in the min-plus semring:

```
class MinPlus(float):

    def __init__(self, value):
        super(MinPlus, self).__init__(value)
      
    def __add__(self, other):
        return MinPlus(min(self, other))
        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return MinPlus(self + other)
```

I want to use sparse matrix multplication and addition, but using the magic methods for multiplication and addition that I have defined above. For example, I have defined a class Bimodule whose multiplication is the following:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
        if len(self.output) != len(other.input):
            raise ValueError("Bimodule shapes are incompatible.")
        mat = {i+";"+j: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y,[self.mat.get(i+';'+k,self.semiring(0)) * other.mat.get(k+';'+j,self.semiring(0)) for k in self.output]) for i in self.input for j in other.output}
        return Bimodule(self.input, other.output, mat,self.semiring)
```

Self.semiring refers to a class I have defined.I want to do the same as above but with large sparse matrices. A solution just for the case of min-plus would be appreciated but I am also interested in sparse multiplication for other classes. For example the antibooleans defined as:

```
   class AntiBoolean():
   def __init__(self, v):
        self.value=v
        
   def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
        
   def __add__(self, other):
        return AntiBoolean(self.value and other.value)
        
   def __mul__(self, other):
        return AntiBoolean(self.value or other.value)
        
   def zero():
        return AntiBoolean(1)     
   def one():
        return AntiBoolean(0)
   
   def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.value==other.value
```

Is it possible to do this in scipy.sparse? Do you know of another library with this functionality? Thank you for your help.

I honestly have no idea where to even start. I've seen an attempt at solution in numpy [Can I use my own Python class with numpy or some other matrix library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578172/can-i-use-my-own-python-class-with-numpy-or-some-other-matrix-library)
but it was not without issues.

Comment: `numpy` arrays with object dtype filled with instances like your class should handle most operators - though at list comprehension speeds.  You could create a COO sparse with them as well, I suspect `toarray()` display will fail as well most math, especially matrix multiplication.  Keep in mind also that the default zeros will still be `0`.

Comment: I don't think scipy.sparse is flexible enough (and it's core is c++ which is hard to mutate from within python). Maybe one of these [GraphBLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphBLAS) implementations is more of a fit (although these are probably less user-friendly than scipy/python).